# Navigation Elements Not Working (Have never seen this before)

Tags: css, wordpress

Thanks in advance guys. I tried searching for the solution but had no idea where to even begin wording it.

So I have a wordpress [website](http://phoenixtuxrental.com/) . The navigation bar on the home page works for mobile and desktop but if you navigate to any of the sub pages that are available (blog, wedding registration) the nav bar items on desktop and mobile are rendered non clickable. Looking for some insight here. Never have I ran into this problem. I feel as if the click function is above the actual word, which makes zero sense to me.

Thanks in advance. Would post code but have no idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just a hint: your `site-container` div is on top of the menu so they are not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your **main content** is covering your menu thats why your menu cant click.. Try adding `z-index:10` in your header with class `site-header`.

Comment: I've been front end developing for a long time and never have I seen this before. It did fix the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: you should be aware how your elements behave in the DOM. Anyways glad that i help you.